# U+C77C ('.notdef') is not available in this font Helvetica-Oblique encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, angular, pdf, pdfbox, boxable

I am using  tags for stylizing the print text for a particular scenario. Which is working fine for other languages but failing in korea language.

Comment: <i> </i> Tags which I am using

Comment: You use a font with **WinAnsiEncoding** which contains Western European glyphs but definitively no Hangul ones like your “일”. Thus, use a different font.

Comment: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#i'm-getting-java.lang.illegalargumentexception%3A-...-is-not-available-in-this-font's-encoding%3A-winansiencoding

Comment: @mkl but the same code is working if I remove <i></i> these tags from the .string. For example: 엔진 장착 엔진 측면 this is my string it will print if I don't use tags but once i add tag like this 엔진 장착 <i> 엔진 </i> 측면. It will break.

Comment: Apparently `<i>` switches the current font to Helvetica-Oblique with **WinAnsiEncoding**. So probably a boxable glitch.

Comment: Have you set the fonts to use by boxable? As far as I can see you would do that with the `FontUtils` method `addDefaultFonts`. If you don't set them, boxable will default to Helvetica variants with **WinAnsiEncoding**.